# XAP packaging failed. windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, xap

I am making a windows phone 8 application, on visual studio 2013 ultimate. Every time i try to build the application or run the emulator it gives two errors:

Error   1   Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream.    PanoramaApp1

Error   2   Could not find file 'c:\users\msaad_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PanoramaApp1\PanoramaApp1\obj\Debug\XapCacheFile.xml'. Please rebuild the solution and try again

I am running windows 8.1 pro, i already uninstalled VS and tried no luck i also tried deleting the bin and obj files and rebuild still no luck. This error happens on an existing solution as well as any new ones. Please help me resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12511848/2998271), maybe related to your problem

Comment: already tried rebuilding the solution?

Answer (score 0):

After installing VS2015 for Windows 10, error 1.

> Error 1 Xap packaging failed. Cannot access a closed Stream

I tested it on project that previously was build successfully - no luck.
Then I tried to deploy xap file with WinPhone Application Deployment tool - no luck again.

After surfing internet I found that only possible solution - is reinstalling VS (something about badly installed Phone tools)

Please, note, that other reason can be that you're not included into your solution some important files (like manifest). Hence before reinstalling try with new clear solution.